# Should services have "events" in a micro service architecture?

Tags: c#, design-patterns, architecture, microservices

I was looking for some kind of best practice about something:
In our application, we have a LOT of services, and there is a lot of interaction between them.

Some services would need to be able to notify that there has been change on their ends.
Our intuitive developer approach would be to just an event in it and register on it. But I've the feeling that this is something that is kind of "dirty".

The service for me was something that was "offered" to the one requesting it, and was, but we should not be aware of the lifecycle of the service(nor should the service garbage collection of the service be prevent because somebody is still registered.

My alternatives are:

- ask to the service an object, on which I will register for event--> I don't find this much cleaner
- Provide to the service an object implementing a CallBack interface, and have the service calling the callback instead of notifying events.
- ???

What do you think is the best practice on this? What would be the cleanest approach?

Comment: There is a known pattern, CQRS (Command Query Responsibility Segregation), you would find lot of examples on how to implement it through events, called EventSourcing. You are not required to use EventSourcing, you can just publish to a Queue and subscribe back to handle the request, you can scale your architecture easily also

Comment: @skjagini Really nice answer, you should post it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a known pattern, CQRS (Command Query Responsibility Segregation), you would find lot of examples on how to implement it through events, called EventSourcing. You are not required to use EventSourcing, you can just publish to a Queue and subscribe back to handle the request, you can scale your architecture easily also

In C#, there is a event sourcing framework, https://github.com/gautema/CQRSlite and a nice explanation on how to use from Sacha, https://www.codeproject.com/articles/991648/cqrs-a-cross-examination-of-how-it-works
 And also you can find more details here, https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=t2AI9hODJ2E&t=1247s

Event Sourcing gets little complicated, unless you really have a need for it, Martin Fowler has few good articles about pros and cons of event sourcing, https://martinfowler.com/eaaDev/EventSourcing.html

Answer (score 0):

What we did in [Careem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Careem)'s microservices system architecture, we have a dedicated service called **Event** which is on top of Amazon SQS. Any service can be a publisher or subscriber of this service. When any service publishes an event using our event publisher SDK API, the event is put into Amazon SQS.Then event processor SDK checks the subscriber list for this particular type of events which is stored in dynamoDB. For each subscriber, there is a separate queue (SQS) and the event processor take the event away from SQS and put it into each subscriber's queue. Then event consumer SDK peaks this event from queue and pushes to associate service. And this whole process is asynchronous meaning the publisher and subscriber services don't have to wait for any response or acknowledgements.

Whether you want to consider it as an dedicated service o not, you will need event to process asynchronous tasks.

Comment: It would mean that when you do an update, you push your changes to the business service A, and expect to be informed that the change has been done on another service? 

For us, it's not really a question of being async, because anyway, notification can come from a different thread.

How do you ensure that only the one responsible of this domain publish the event?